# I want to code for save html in C#

Tags: c#, .net

I am using 'save as html' to save file as html.
My code is:

```
string fileName = "";
string htmlpfilepath;
string[] parts;
try
{
    htmlpfilepath = Server.MapPath(ClinicalDocFile);
    parts = ClinicalDocFile.Split('/');

    if (parts.Length > 0)
        fileName = parts[parts.Length - 1];

    HttpResponse response = HttpContext.Current.Response;
    response.Clear();
    response.AddHeader("Content-Type", "text/HTML");
    response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition",
        "attachment; filename=" + fileName + "; size=" + fileName.Length.ToString());
    response.Flush();
    response.WriteFile(htmlpfilepath);
    response.Flush();
    response.End();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    FW.Fission.WebSite.Code.Utilities.SiteUtilities.HandleException(ex);
}
```

I am getting the following error in `response.End();` line.

> Enable to evaluate expression because the code is optimized or a native frame is on top of the call stack.

Comment: That isn't a program error. It is a debugger problem. Are you running in debug mode?

Comment: It only tells you that it can't tell you what the real error is. In your project properties->build check off "Optimize code", then see what error says. Of course, you have to rebuild

Comment: I am getting same error.

Comment: @Swati Pandey. so, if the code is no longer optimized that this is something else. Just make sure that you removed "optimization" option anf you build that configuration AND you produce "full debug" information. Make sure these 3 conditions exist - this is good beginning. Again, this is not a fix - just to see what is going on

Answer (score 0):

If you use the `Response.End` a ThreadAbortException exception occurs. You can use a try-catch statement to catch this exception.

The `Response.End` method ends the page execution and shifts the execution to the Application_EndRequest event in the application's event pipeline. The line of code that follows `Response.End` is not executed.

Check [Here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/312629/en-us)

Also check this [Article](http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2009/May/21/Dont-use-ResponseEnd-with-OutputCache) and [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/315235/Response-End-throwing-error)

-- Hope it helps .

Answer (score 0):

To work around this problem, use one of the following methods:

For `Response.End`, call the `HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest` 
method instead of Response.End to bypass the code execution to the `Application_EndRequest` event.

For `Response.Redirect`, use an overload, Response.Redirect(String url, bool endResponse) that passes false for the endResponse parameter to suppress the internal call to Response.End.

For example:

```
Response.Redirect ("nextpage.aspx", false);
```

If you use this workaround, the code that follows Response.Redirect is executed.
    For Server.Transfer, use the Server.Execute method instead.

Got from this link 
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/312629/en-us

`response.redirect` also faces the same problem you should be adding false

but in case if you are downloading word document file response.end() should be used, if not the word document downloaded will be in corrupted format.